# Ajuda em como utilizar setItem e getItem do localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, front-end, localstorage

Estou tentando salvar uma resposta, mas não estou conseguindo, toda vez que dou um refresh a resposta anterior volta. Segue o que eu estou tentando implementar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>question and answer</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
        What is the capital of Brazil?   
        </p>
        <p id="resposta">
        Rio de Janeiro   
        </p>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("p").dblclick(function () {
                var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();

                $(this).addClass("respostaEmEdicao");
                $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + conteudoOriginal + "' />");
                $(this).children().first().focus();

                $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                    if (e.which == 13) {
                        var novoConteudo = $(this).val();
                        $(this).parent().text(novoConteudo);
                        localStorage.content = $('#resposta').html();
                        $('#resposta').html(localStorage.content);
                        $(this).parent().removeClass("respostaEmEdicao");
                    }  
                });


            $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
                $(this).parent().text(conteudoOriginal);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("celulaEmEdicao");
            });
            });

        });
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2):

Tenta desse jeito:

Primeiro você coloca o seu dado no localStorage e nomeia ele:

```
localStorage.setItem('Content', $('#resposta').html());
```

Depois você pega ele no localStorage pela nome que você colocou:

```
$('#resposta').html(localStorage.getItem('Content'));
```

Isso vai retornar o valor que você atribuiu.

Espero ter ajudado